# var undefined getting value $ _GET ['page']

Tags: php, pagination

I want paging is a content of a news blog. Everything works correctly, the page content is successful. But I get an error screen displays PHP:

**Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 146**

code with the line that gives the error:

```
$maxreg = 1;

    $pag = $_GET['page'];

if (!isset($pag) || empty($pag)){

      $min = 0;
      $pag = 1;  

}else{

      if($pag == 1){

            $min = 0;

      }else{

            $min = $maxreg * $pag;
            $min = $min - $maxreg;

      }
}

include("js/class.AutoPagination.php");
$obj = new AutoPagination(contar_contenido(), $pag);

mostrar_contenido($min,$maxreg);

echo $obj->_paginateDetails();
```

The line gives the error is this:

```
$ page = $ _GET ['page'];
```

The first page by default index.php and contains no var in the url.
I do not understand why if fails below by a conditional var I determine if that has content or not.

Should not show any error php, could someone give me a solution? Thanks

Comment: make sure `?page=123` is in your URL (in your browser URL where you type)

Comment: It works perfectly, I went to page three and takes me to page 3. On that page does not fail. The url: http://localhost/index.php?&page=3

Everything is perfect, only fails when you first open the page and there is no var on url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quote;

*Declare your variables. Or use isset() to check if they are declared before referencing them;*

[PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Is that the problem, but how could build conditional to not show any error?

Comment: But it is that it is, then the variable has no value. Should not display the error because the variable does not exist at that instant.

Comment: The answer is described there.. 

`$pag = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';`

Comment: True, he had not noticed. Thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do

`$pag = $_GET['page'];`

Check if $_GET['page'] is set first:

```
if(!isset($_GET['page']) || empty($_GET['page'])) {

    $min = 0;
    $pag = 1;

}else{

    if($pag == 1){

        $min = 0;

    }else{

        $min = $maxreg * $pag;
        $min = $min - $maxreg;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thus it gives me error when moving to page 2. It drives me to report:

Undefined variable: p in C: \ wamp \ www \ index.php on line 146 :(

Comment: It happens because the value of the url var page to be applied. Otherwise not work, you know?

Comment: To find out which page these need to: $pag = $_GET['page'];

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I've built so, assigning a value to the variable empty get in if it is indefinite.
Maybe it's a very elegant solution, but it works perfect paging.

```
 if(!isset($_GET['page']) || empty($_GET['page'])) {

        $_GET['page']="";

        }


        $maxreg = 2;
        $min = 0;
        $pag = $_GET['page'];
```

I think the second conditional left over.

I leave it here in case anyone has the same problem. This way you can fix it.